# Make a grid 3d looking

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

Kind of new to Silverlight, how can I make a grid 3d-looking (kind of like how the Silverlight progress bar visually stands out).  I feel like I have tried everything but I have ran out of ideas.  Could anyone give me a code snippet that can do this?

Comment: can you explain more what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the [DropShadowEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect%28VS.95%29.aspx)?

```
<data:DataGrid>
  <data:DataGrid.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect />
  </data:DataGrid.Effect>
  ...
  ...
</data:DataGrid>
```

You can use this on other controls as well of course.

Creating a sunken effect is all about the illusion of lighting. If you draw a border around the element with a dark color on the top and left and lighter color on the bottom and right you get the impression that the content has been sunk into the surface. Switching the shade will give the effect of the content being raised.

Here is a small example to demonstrate

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" >
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Lightgray">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
      <!-- Sunken -->
      <Grid Width="100" Height="25" Background="Wheat" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <!-- Draw the 3d border -->
        <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Rectangle Width="1" Fill="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <Rectangle Width="1" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <!-- Put your content in this Grid -->
        <Grid>
          <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Sunken" />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <!-- Raised -->
      <Grid Width="100" Height="25" Background="Wheat" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <!-- Draw the 3d border -->
        <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Rectangle Width="1" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <Rectangle Width="1" Fill="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <!-- Put your content in this Grid -->
        <Grid>
          <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Raised" />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: This really helps thank you, is there a way to give it a sunken effect look? otherwise il have to stick to this but thanks for the reply :)